# Multi warehouses access rights?

Tags: odoo

My client has a company with the following structure:

- The HO                               (**HO**)
- The Manufacturing Plant              (**MF**)
- Other warehouses                     (**OW**)

Each of these branches has its own local warehouse as described, respectively.

The warehouse access rights should be distributed over these warehouses, as each stock keeper should only deal with his warehouse.

In Odoo Sales, each sales team member can be restricted to see only his leads.
However, in Odoo Warehouse, I cannot see such access rights.

Please help with your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Add following record rule to warehouse

```
['|',('company_id','=',False),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx Viraj for your reply, but this doesn't solve my problem.
I'm talking about separating each warehouse moves from other warehouses.

Comment: I just want to prevent each warehouse keeper from making picking in another warehouse,

Comment: In this user can create picking for it's company and it's all child companies
['|',('company_id','=',False),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])]

You can change it to 
['|',('company_id','=',False),('company_id','=',user.company_id.id)]
And try because this rule prevent each user to deal with another company.

Comment: But you didn't mention the warehouse in your filter, so do you think it will work?